# style sheet remove border of window

Tags: pyqt, stylesheet, designer

is it possible to remove border of window using "style sheet" in qt designer ?

i have to remove it within qt designer, and i dont want to convert it into python.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to control your window border would be setting window flags parameter in the constructor, smth like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

or call:

```
your_window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
```

for your window anywhere in the code.

hope this helps, regards